# What is feminine form of "борец"?

Tags: одним-словом

I thought it was "борыня" but was corrected.

Comment: And whoever corrected you, what did he or she say?

Comment: @Em1 I was said it was incorrect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Борец`, `полководец` as well аs `товарищ`, `инженер`, `министр`,`лидер` (though colloqial `лидерша` exists), `вождь`, `лауреат`, `член` and some other words do not have feminine form.

It's not that easy, all you can do is just to remember such words, since other words wiсh belong to related context exists in feminine, e. g.: руководительница, приятельница, воительница, номинантка (de-facto way more acceptable than лауреатка), атаманша.

Besides, in modern Russian, even if it existed such feminine form, it most probably would be `борчиха` (compare to `пловец/пловчиха`), but very unlikely it would be `борыня`.

Also, it worth to mention that some words in feminine form have slightly different meaning. `Офицерша`, as well as `генеральша` or `капитанша` are common terms for referencing women married to a member of armed force.

Comment: It seems to me that though борчиха could be acceptable in sport context, it would sound ungood in political context.

Comment: @Anixx: In political context you would say Она настоящий борец... Борчиха will sound funny in any context.

Comment: Interestingly, word _борчиха_ seems to exist.  I did a google search for that word - and was quite surprised by the number and quality of the matches.

Comment: @AleksG this word exists only in that sense that is relatively often is used by mistake, especially by sportсasters. Nevertheless, there is no such word, just like there is no such word like `Норвег`, but it is used sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

Правильно говорить "борец"

> Борец Власова получила бронзовую медаль на олимпийских играх 2012

Можно употреблять "женщина-борец", если из контекста не понятно, что речь идёт о женщине. Но лучше всего избегать вообще таких случаев. Например:

> Власова получила бронзовую медаль по борьбе среди женщин

Многие профессии не имеют женского рода: "инженер", "анестезиолог", "стоматолог", "копирайтер".

Answer (score 3):

The best variant would be *женщина-борец*.

Comment: Доктор Куин, женщина-врач)))

Answer (score 0):

Борчиха (борчихи - мн.ч.) - common, not literatural form. Classical Russian don't contains female form for борец. This profession assosiates with a male only.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE.  While your answer is legitimate, it does not seem to provide any new information in addition to that already contained in other answers.  Please refrain from reposting others' answers unless you want to expand on them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor and/or repetitive answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.

Answer (score -2):

борчиха (yes, it sounds awful) and
пловчиха (female swimmer)

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE.  We welcome elaborate, expanded answers, which explain the topic/subject in details.  It is also appropriate to cite specific sources of information when applicable.  Please refrain from repeating existing answers without further expanding upon them.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor and/or repetitive answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.